# Loop Through Power Pivot, Pivot Table Filter and Print to PDF

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, pivot-table, powerpivot

The objective is to Loop through an Excel Power Pivot, Pivot Table and print each Filtered Result to PDF in a specific file location.

When the code gets to the for loop of the output it is giving me an error

> "Run Time Error - 438 Object doesnt support the property or method"

on the line `For Each pi In pt`

```
Sub Button1_Click()
 Dim strPath As String
 Dim wksSource As Worksheet
 Dim pt As PivotTable
 Dim pf As PivotField
 Dim pi As PivotItem
 Dim cf As CubeField

 Set wksSource = Worksheets("Summary for Each Analyst")

 Set pt = wksSource.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

 Set cf = pt.CubeFields("[Std_MainData].[CredentialingAnalyst]")

 If cf.Orientation <> xlPageField Then
  MsgBox "There's no 'Credentialing Analyst' field in the Report Filter. Try again!", vbExclamation
 End If

 strPath = "H:\"

 If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"

  ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

  pt.PivotCache.Refresh

  For Each pi In pt
   wksSource.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strPath & pi.Name & ".pdf"
  Next pi
```

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: pi belongs to pf, not to pt. You can't say "pi in pt". It must be "pi in pt.pf. For example: Worksheets("sheet1").PivotTables(1).PivotFields("year").PivotItems("1998").Visible = False

Comment: Good morning, is it possible to comment as code? i tried changing my code to "pi in pt.pf" and it is giving me the same error as before written above. Remember this is a Power Pivot, so it is cubefield based, i do not know if that makes a difference or not to cycle through the pivot table for that cubefield. @RADO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've struggled with this same issue this whole weekend and I finally got it working for me looping through a slicer instead of report filter.

```
'This VBA will loop through your Power Pivot slicer and print the results to PDF.
'To get it working change slicer name and storage location in below VBA.

Private Sub PowerPivotLoopSlicerPrintPDF()
Dim SC As SlicerCache
Dim SL As SlicerCacheLevel
Dim SI As SlicerItem

Set SC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Kolonne1") 'Add slicer name between " "
Set SL = SC.SlicerCacheLevels(1)

'c(ounter) is set to 1, ready to begin
c = 1


'Repeat the a loop until number of prints exceeds number of items in slicer
Do While c <= SC.SlicerCacheLevels.Item.Count + 1

'This makes sure that SI is the correct slicer. Needed for corrent file name.
    For Each SI In SL.SlicerItems
        If SI.Selected = True Then
        SlicerverdiIndex = c
    Exit For
        End If
    Next SI


    'PRINT CODE
    Dim FName           As String
    Dim FPath           As String

    'Define file path for printed file storage
    FPath = "C:\Users\remia\Desktop\VBA\"   'Choose your filepath
    FName = SI.SourceName

    'Define WHAT to print and how to build file name
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    FPath & "\" & FName & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False

    'PRINT CODE FINISHED

'Sets the slicer to the last item in the list
If SlicerverdiIndex = 1 Then
    SlicerverdiIndex = SC.SlicerCacheLevels.Item.Count + 1
End If
SC.VisibleSlicerItemsList = SL.SlicerItems(SlicerverdiIndex - 1).Name

'Adds 1 to the counter, will loop until end of slicer has been reached.
c = c + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: this is awesome! thanks so much, however i am getting a problem the first line Set SC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Kolonne1") is providing an error in my workbook. i think i am having trouble targeting the filter its called credentialing analyst and its located on ("[Std_MainData].[CredentialingAnalyst]")

Comment: Add the column you want to filter on as a slicer in the workbook. Right click on the slicer, slicer settings, then you will see "Name to use in formulas". Thats the name to target with the SC line :)

Comment: this worked perfectly!! thanks so much! i added and upvoted and verified your post!! @fenixen

Answer (score 0):

Please change pt to pv as RADO pointed out:

```
For Each pv In pt.PivotFields
   wksSource.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strPath & pv.Name & ".pdf"
Next pv
```

Thanks

Comment: Good morning, what are you defining pv as? i tried just copying and pasting you code into the workbook, that didnt work. Then i changed defined pv as Pivot item, dim pv as PivotItem and that did not work.

Comment: also thanks for your response, just wanted to point out that this is an CubeField Power Pivot, Pivot Table.

Comment: Can you provide sample data so that I can reproduce the issue?